# Combine two (three) macros

Tags: c++, macros

i am currently working on a project where I am using the same macros over and over in the same order for a serialization of a class. I Am using Boost Macros for serialization.
Namely:

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(SameClass)
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_FACTORY_0(SameClass)
```

How can I combine these two into one Macro.

```
 #define registrateDMP(arg) BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(arg) BOOST_SERIALIZATION_FACTORY_0(arg)
```

does not work. Furthermore i would like a to add a third macro into the complete macro if that is actually possible.

```
#define DMPTYPE_BASICDMP_GUID boost::serialization::guid<SameClass>()
```

If I use the three macros independently my program works, but since the calls for the macros are always in the same order and i use them for a lot of different cases and want to use them for more as well it would be nice to simplify the commands to one macro. Can anybody help? Thank you

Comment: Could you show the errors you get when you use `registrateDMP` please?  I would expect it to work.  (BTW `registerDMP` might be better English if you care.)

Comment: `unknown location(0): fatal error in "test_BasicDMP": std::logic_error: basic_string::_S_construct null not valid` is the error i get in the testcase which normally works.

Comment: This is a bug in your code that occurs at runtime, and has nothing to do with any macro. If there was any problem with the macro, your code will not compile in the first place.

Comment: To clearify, i am not using strings, directly. I am serialising a class which can be later adressed via a string given by the guid. But nethertheless, if i execute the commands seperatly i have a working version, just combinded it is not working

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That's not *necessarily* true.  You can get macros to generate output which is syntactically valid - but which does the wrong thing.  (But it does sound plausible.)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That might be, but then again. The programm is working as i intend it while i am using the macros independently. Just while using the combination it stops working. therefore i am trying to under stand the why.

Comment: The "registrateDMP" macro you've shown is completely identical to explicitly using the two component macros, one after another. This cannot be disputed. That's the only thing you need to understand. Your runtime bug has nothing to do with the macros.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Then i will try to figure out what i am missing in my other code when you are saying that the macro should be working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#define registrateDMP(arg)\
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(arg)\
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_FACTORY_0(arg)
```

Or this:

```
#define registrateDMP(arg)\
{{BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(arg);}\
{BOOST_SERIALIZATION_FACTORY_0(arg);}}
```